# Wso2 IoT : ERROR - DeviceMgtAPIUtils Exception occurred while starting the Task service

Tags: wso2-iot

When I back up Platform Configurations on wso2 IoT (I click to save), in the console I have an error:

```
[IoT-Core] ERROR - DeviceMgtAPIUtils Exception occurred while starting the Task service.
org.wso2.carbon.policy.mgt.common.PolicyMonitoringTaskException: Policy monitoring is not enabled in the cdm-config.xml
```

Thank or your reponse

Tof

Answer (score 0):

Enable `<MonitoringEnable>` inside `<PolicyConfiguration>` in /core/repository/conf/cdm-config.xml. Then restart server.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring Enable should be true in MonitoringEnable element not "Enable".

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for your help